# Mysqldump - Reading malformed varbinary value

Tags: mysql

The other developer on a project I'm working on exported a database using mysqldump during migration to a new server without waiting for me to check that they'd exported it correctly, trying to load the database now we see that the varbinary field `ip` is throwing the error "Data too long for column" when trying to insert data, looking further into this I believe that --hex-blob was forgotten during export which has caused the ip column to hold malformed data.

Anyway, my question is, is there a way to solve this and transform the currently held data back into the proper varbinary form or not.

And yes the old server is now gone so redumping is out of the question :(

Thanks. p.s: please don't call me out on the terrible practice taken

```
mysql> source /home/migration/user_data.sql
Database changed
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
ERROR 1406 (22001): Data too long for column 'ip' at row 1
```

Comment: What is the definition of column `ip`, what is the value of it in the first row of the insert statements?

Comment: `ip` varbinary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',

Comment: value just appears as some symbols, for example '��F�'

Comment: But the IP should be simple numbers

Comment: @Jens They apparently have it encoded in binary, not the text representation like `192.168.1.1`

Comment: I know it should be, it was stored in varbinary so it should've saved as, for example, 0xC0A80001 for 192.168.0.1, but instead mysqldump saved it as random characters such as &\0\0��k��

Comment: Can you share some sample data?

Comment: *mysqldump saved it as random characters* I am not sure if it is saved in this way, or your editor shows this in that way

Comment: @Jens regardless of how my editor shows it, the format it saved in is definitely wrong

Comment: Maybe, but hard to help without any information about the old and the new database

Comment: You have to look at the byte values of the characters that appear in the field. If you know the original value thst should be there, you can convert the byte values back to the IP addresses.

Comment: @Shadow thanks, I'll start trying this now and see what I can get working

Comment: @Shadow is there documentation anywhere from someone who's done this before by chance?